# How do I zoom the view when the player zooms in or out?

Tags: swift, xcode, pinchzoom

So I just learned how to make a view zoom in and out, and I did it for my gamescene but theres just a black box right outside the view, like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu3F9.jpg)

Here's my code that I used to allow zooming in and out, this is in my didMove function

```
let pinch = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinch(sender:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(pinch)
```

and this is inside no function, just the GameScene class

```
@objc func handlePinch(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        guard sender.view != nil else { return }

        if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
            sender.view?.transform = (sender.view?.transform.scaledBy(x: sender.scale, y: sender.scale))!
                sender.scale = 1.0
              }
          }
```

How would I change the view whenever someone zooms in or out?